# DB2: lag functions really slow

Tags: db2

I have a big CTE that outputs data with about 50 rows. Let's call this *output_no_1*. Now, If I add another step in my CTE , to manipulate *output_no_1*, i.e. add some columns dependent on the columns of *output_no_1*, my code takes 20 times as long to run.

I wish to understand why that is...

I need to make a bunch of new columns in *output_no_2* (*output_no_1* contains year_month and I want to compare sales and other stuff from one period to the next):

```
upper part of the CTE
.
.
.
.
,output_no_2 as (
select output_no_1.*
        --comment
        ,lag(sales_bread_shelf_50000   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_bread_shelf_50000
        ,lag(sales_bread_shelf_50001   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_bread_shelf_50001
        ,lag(sales_bread_shelf_50002   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_bread_shelf_50002
        ,lag(sales_bread_shelf_50003   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_bread_shelf_50003
        ,lag(sales_jam_shelf__50000   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_jam_shelf__50000
        ,lag(sales_jam_shelf__50001   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_jam_shelf__50001
        ,lag(sales_jam_shelf__50002   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_jam_shelf__50002
        ,lag(sales_jam_shelf__50003   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_jam_shelf__50003
        ,lag(sales_honey_shelf__50000   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_honey_shelf__50000
        ,lag(sales_honey_shelf__50001   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_honey_shelf__50001
        ,lag(sales_honey_shelf__50002   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_honey_shelf__50002
        ,lag(sales_honey_shelf__50003   ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_sales_honey_shelf__50003
        --comment
        ,lag(NO_honey_shelf_50000  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_honey_shelf_50000
        ,lag(NO_honey_shelf_50001  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_honey_shelf_50001
        ,lag(NO_honey_shelf_50002  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_honey_shelf_50002
        ,lag(NO_honey_shelf_50003  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_honey_shelf_50003
        ,lag(NO_jam_shelf_50000  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_jam_shelf_50000
        ,lag(NO_jam_shelf_50001  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_jam_shelf_50001
        ,lag(NO_jam_shelf_50002  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_jam_shelf_50002
        ,lag(NO_jam_shelf_50003  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_jam_shelf_50003
        ,lag(NO_bread_shelf_50000  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_bread_shelf_50000
        ,lag(NO_bread_shelf_50001  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_bread_shelf_50001
        ,lag(NO_bread_shelf_50002  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_bread_shelf_50002
        ,lag(NO_bread_shelf_50003  ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_bread_shelf_50003
        --comment
        ,lag(all_merch_50000 ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_all_merch_50000
        ,lag(all_merch_50001 ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_all_merch_50001
        ,lag(all_merch_50002 ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_all_merch_50002
        ,lag(all_merch_50003 ) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_all_merch_50003
        ,lag(NO_all_merch_50000) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_all_merch_50000
        ,lag(NO_all_merch_50001) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_all_merch_50001
        ,lag(NO_all_merch_50002) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_all_merch_50002
        ,lag(NO_all_merch_50003) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_NO_all_merch_50003
        --comment
        ,lag(customer_paid_cash) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_customer_paid_cash
        ,lag(customer_paid_card) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_customer_paid_card
        ,lag(customer_paid_stole) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_customer_paid_stole
        ,lag(customer_paid_cried) over(partition by year_month order by year_month) as lag_customer_paid_cried

from output_no_1
)
select * from output_no_2
```

Comment: Can you expand CLT?

Comment: Also, why is this tagged [tag:sas]?  Looks like it should be [tag:db2]?

Comment: Thanks! I meant CTE :)

Comment: `partition by year_month order by year_month` doesn't make much sense, as all `year_month` values will be the same within the partition, you will therefore waste CPU cycles ordering them.

Comment: But simply paritioning will not sort it?

Comment: @Erosennin - we need to see `output_no_1` before we can even guess at what might be slow.  Good performance of `LAG` usually requires backing of an index, and going through a CTE can hinder that.  To clarify mustaccio's comment, the ordering inside the `OVER` clause _only applies to that partition/column_, not the rowset - if you need all rows sorted, you need to specify an outer `ORDER BY` clause as normal.  My guess is you don't need the `PARTITION BY` sub-clause here.

Comment: Aha, very interesting. I reasoned since output_no_1 was fast, output_no_2 should also be fast, ie sorting 50 rows many times should go fast, even though I create many variables. I thought things worked step by step... I think I’m lacking some fundamental understanding here.

Answer (score 0):

May be try Something like this:

```
with output_no_1b as ( 
select rownumber() over(partition by year_month order by year_month) rang, f1.*
from output_no_1 f1
)
,output_no_2 as (
select f1.*, 

f2.sales_bread_shelf_50000  Lag_sales_bread_shelf_50000 ,
f2.sales_bread_shelf_50001  Lag_sales_bread_shelf_50001 ,
f2.sales_bread_shelf_50002  Lag_sales_bread_shelf_50002 ,
f2.sales_bread_shelf_50003  Lag_sales_bread_shelf_50003 ,
f2.sales_jam_shelf__50000   Lag_sales_jam_shelf__50000  ,
f2.sales_jam_shelf__50001   Lag_sales_jam_shelf__50001  ,
f2.sales_jam_shelf__50002   Lag_sales_jam_shelf__50002  ,
f2.sales_jam_shelf__50003   Lag_sales_jam_shelf__50003  ,
f2.sales_honey_shelf__50000 Lag_sales_honey_shelf__50000,
f2.sales_honey_shelf__50001 Lag_sales_honey_shelf__50001,
f2.sales_honey_shelf__50002 Lag_sales_honey_shelf__50002,
f2.sales_honey_shelf__50003 Lag_sales_honey_shelf__50003,

f2.NO_honey_shelf_50000 Lag_NO_honey_shelf_50000,
f2.NO_honey_shelf_50001 Lag_NO_honey_shelf_50001,
f2.NO_honey_shelf_50002 Lag_NO_honey_shelf_50002,
f2.NO_honey_shelf_50003 Lag_NO_honey_shelf_50003,
f2.NO_jam_shelf_50000   Lag_NO_jam_shelf_50000  ,
f2.NO_jam_shelf_50001   Lag_NO_jam_shelf_50001  ,
f2.NO_jam_shelf_50002   Lag_NO_jam_shelf_50002  ,
f2.NO_jam_shelf_50003   Lag_NO_jam_shelf_50003  ,
f2.NO_bread_shelf_50000 Lag_NO_bread_shelf_50000,
f2.NO_bread_shelf_50001 Lag_NO_bread_shelf_50001,
f2.NO_bread_shelf_50002 Lag_NO_bread_shelf_50002,
f2.NO_bread_shelf_50003 Lag_NO_bread_shelf_50003,

f2.all_merch_50000  Lag_all_merch_50000 ,
f2.all_merch_50001   Lag_all_merch_50001  ,
f2.all_merch_50002   Lag_all_merch_50002  ,
f2.all_merch_50003   Lag_all_merch_50003  ,
f2.NO_all_merch_50000 Lag_NO_all_merch_50000,
f2.NO_all_merch_50001 Lag_NO_all_merch_50001,
f2.NO_all_merch_50002 Lag_NO_all_merch_50002,
f2.NO_all_merch_50003 Lag_NO_all_merch_50003,

f2.customer_paid_cash Lag_customer_paid_cash,
f2.customer_paid_card Lag_customer_paid_card,
f2.customer_paid_stole Lag_customer_paid_stole,
f2.customer_paid_cried Lag_customer_paid_cried,

from output_no_1b f1
left outer join lateral
(
   select * from output_no_1b f0
   where (f0.year_month, f0.rang - 1)=(f1.year_month, f1.rang)
   fetch first rows only
) f2 on 1=1

)
select * from output_no_2
```